# What is the difference between Pushlet and Server Sent Events?

Tags: push-notification, xmlhttprequest, streaming, comet, server-sent-events

Is there any difference between [Pushlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Pushlet) and [Server Sent Events](http://cjihrig.com/blog/the-server-side-of-server-sent-events/) technologies?
As far as I understand both of them use the same mechanism, create a connection to the server and leave it open in order to receive new data.
Are those technologies similar, and if so when should each of them be used?

**Update:** After a more detailed research on the web, I came to this [article](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/rg30/2.html) which states that Pushlet is a Java servlet library based on HTTP Streaming, and supports either Page or Service Streaming; it is a tool which helps a developer to perform Comet streaming.

So my next question is is there a difference between Comet streaming and Server Sent Events? As mentioned [here](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/rg28/index.html)

> in a Web application using streaming Comet, the browser opens a single persistent connection to the server for all Comet events and handles them incrementally on the browser side.

Comment: Please update yours links, 404 not found

Comment: Looks like 3 out of 4 links have been removed. I will try to find similar articles to replace broken links.